# Python Function Undefined

Tags: python-3.x

I am attempting to use timeit to create a program that will eventually print out the bigO of another program. If I try to use a lambda instead of a string argument, the program just hangs. If I use a string arg as seen below, I get the posted error.

```
pdralston@jeff:~$ python3 as10.py cs23_as10_constant
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "as10.py", line 15, in <module>
    elapsed_1 = timeit.timeit("func_run('1024')")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/timeit.py", line 213, in timeit
    return Timer(stmt, setup, timer, globals).timeit(number)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/timeit.py", line 178, in timeit
    timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
  File "<timeit-src>", line 6, in inner
NameError: name 'func_run' is not defined
```

Unhappy code

```
import sys
import subprocess
import timeit

command = sys.argv[1]#command line arg for executable to be tested
def func_run(parameter): #looks pretty defined to me...
        subprocess.run([command, parameter])#runs the executable with an arg for data sample size
answers = { #will use this for output eventually 
    0: "O(1)",
    1: "O(log n)",
    2: "O(n)",
    3: "O(n log n)",
    4: "O(n^2)",
    5: "O(n^3)"}
elapsed_1 = timeit.timeit("func_run('1024')")#also tried lambda: func_run("1024") instead of a string
elapsed_2 = timeit.timeit("func_run('4096')")
elapsed_growth = elapsed_2 / elapsed_1
print(elapsed_growth)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your function.

```
import sys
import subprocess
import timeit

command = sys.argv[1]

def wrapper(func, *args, **kwargs):
     def wrapped():
         return func(*args, **kwargs)
     return wrapped

def func_run(parameter):
        subprocess.run([command, parameter])

yourArgs_1 = '1024'
yourArgs_2 = '4096'

wrapped_1 = wrapper(func_run, yourArgs_1)
wrapped_2 = wrapper(func_run, yourArgs_2)

answers = { 
    0: "O(1)",
    1: "O(log n)",
    2: "O(n)",
    3: "O(n log n)",
    4: "O(n^2)",
    5: "O(n^3)"}

elapsed_1 = timeit.timeit(wrapped_1)
elapsed_2 = timeit.timeit(wrapped_2)
# Provide number of execution with number argument in timit function
# timeit.timeit(wrapped_1, number=10)
elapsed_growth = elapsed_2 / elapsed_1
print(elapsed_growth)
```

Comment: Using your code, the program is unfortunately just freezing.

Comment: Could you tell me what are you passing as argument ?

Comment: "python3 as10.py cs23_as10_constant"
this is the command that we run for testing the programs. We have a series of default programs on our server for this purpose.

Comment: You need to provide number of execution to timeit function timeit.timeit(wrapped_2, number=100)

Comment: @DRoc101 Are you SURE that it worked? I am getting a long error message stating that the script I want to test is not there "FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'O[n].py'", where my own script doing from my point of view the right thing as you intended runs without any problem. **DOES** the script above give you different elapsed_growth values for scripts needing `O(n)` (giving ~2 as `elapsed_growth`) and scripts `O(n^2)` (giving ~16 as `elapsed_growth`)?

Comment: @Claudio Yes the code is working as expected. I got a 50/50 on my assignment. It could be that the file you are trying to access is not in the same directory as the script, meaning that you would have to give a more complete path to the file in-order for the script to work. Also, it is worth noting that linear order would return a relative ratio of 4 in the above code as I am using a data set of 2^10 and then a a data set of 2^10.